# My classification neural network is having logic issues

Tags: c++, machine-learning, neural-network

I made my first 1 dimensional classification neural network in C++ in which the logic is as follows:

- If input <= 1: f(x) = 1
- If input > 1:  f(x) = -1

I made it extremely sloppy at first, but now that I know it works I changed the code to be more generic for number of inputs so I can easily change the size of [x] when I feel so inclined. However the new code is not getting the logic right; It comes out with totally wrong answers and similar weights for all inputs.
* Keep in mind that my variable names are stupid and variable "outputs" is actually the training set.

This is my final output from the program:

```
Input: 1 ; Class: 1 ; Eval = -1
Weight for node 1: -2
Input: 2 ; Class: -1 ; Eval = -1
Weight for node 2: -2
Input: 3 ; Class: -1 ; Eval = -1
Weight for node 3: -1
```

The "Class" is what it should be, and "Eval" is what it actually is. Notice the first input does not match it's training element.

## Original Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double weights[2] = {0.0};

double classify(double);

int main() {
   double inputs[2] = {1.0, 2.0};
   double outputs[2] = {1.0, -1.0};
   int index = 0;
   bool trained = false;

   while(!trained) {
      trained = true;

       cout << inputs[0] << " , " << outputs[0] << " eval = " << classify(inputs[0]) << endl;
       cout << inputs[1] << " , " << outputs[1] << " eval = " << classify(inputs[1]) << endl;
       cout << "Weights = " << weights[0] << " , " << weights[1] << endl << endl;

       index = 0;

       while(index < 2) {
           double input = inputs[index];
           double output = outputs[index];
           double dClass = classify(input);

           if (dClass != output) {
               weights[0] += output * input;
               weights[1] += output * 1.0;
               trained = false;
           }
           index++;
       }
   }

   return 0;
}

double classify(double input){
double products[2];
double sum = 0;
double threshhold;

// Sumation of inputs
products[0] = input * weights[0];
products[1] = 1.0 * weights[1];
sum         = products[0] + products[1];

// Threshold function
if (sum >= 0.0)
    threshhold = 1.0;
else
    threshhold = -1.0;

return threshhold;
}
```

## Modified Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#define NODES 3

using namespace std;

double weights[NODES] = {0.0};

double classify(double);

int main() {
    double inputs[NODES] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
    double outputs[NODES] = {1.0, -1.0, -1.0};
    int index = 0;
    bool trained = false;
    index = 0;

    // While the classifications are incrorrect
    while(!trained) {
       trained = true;

       while(index < NODES) {
           double input = inputs[index];           // Input nodes
           double output = outputs[index];         // Desired class
           double dClass = classify(input);        // Calculated class

           // If calculated class != desired class:
           // adjust the weights
           if (dClass != output) {
               for(int i = 0; i < NODES - 1; i++)
                  weights[i] += output * input;

               // Bias weight
               weights[NODES-1] += output * 1.0;

               trained = false;
           }
           index++;

           // Debugging
           for(int i = 0; i < NODES; i++){
              cout << "Input: " << inputs[i] << " ; Class: " << outputs[i] << " ; Eval = "      << dClass << endl;
              cout << "Weight for node " << i + 1 << ": " << weights[i] << endl;
           }
           cout << endl;
           }

    }

    return 0;
}

double classify(double input){
   double products[NODES];
   double sum = 0;
   double threshhold;

   // Attach weights to nodes
   for(int i = 0; i < NODES - 1; i++)
       products[i] = input * weights[i];

   // Last node with bias
   products[NODES-1] = 1.0 * weights[NODES-1];

   // Sumation of inputs
   for(int i = 0; i < NODES; i++)
       sum += products[i];

   // Threshold function
   if (sum >= 0.0)
       threshhold = 1.0;
   else
       threshhold = -1.0;

   return threshhold;
}
```

If you can answer this question, then I have a follow up if you feel like giving me input (though it is closer to a conversational question). I am new to implementing neural networks and am curious as to what you all think are the est data structures for an average back propagating, fixed topology ANN, as well as for a dynamic one (that would perhaps be used in neuro evolution). Is there a good neural network implementation convention to go by?

Comment: When I run this it appears to give the desired result. Maybe you could tell us what result you want, and what you get.

Comment: Are you running the modified code or the original code? Because the original code works.

Comment: I ran the modified code.

Comment: When I run it, the weights are all the same and the desired outputs of 1.0, -1.0, -1.0 are not achieved when it terminates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears we have a mystery. Before we get too far into it, try making this small change to `main()` (just a change in what it prints) and tell us what you get. Don't just say that it gives the wrong answers or that the desired results are not achieved, *tell us what it actually produces*.

**OBSOLETE CODE DELETED**

**EDIT:**
You have two problems. First, you're a little confused about what this code is doing; the number of *nodes* and the number of *elements in your training set* are fundamentally independent, but you're treating them as identical and getting confused about which one you're iterating over. Second, you neglect to reset `index` at the end of the inner loop. Change this:

```
  // Debugging
  for(int i = 0; i < NODES; i++){
    cout << "Input: " << inputs[i] << " ; Class: " << outputs[i] << " ; Eval = "      << dClass << endl;
    cout << "Weight for node " << i + 1 << ": " << weights[i] << endl;
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```

to this:

```
  // Debugging
  cout << "Input: " << input << " ; Class: " << output << " ; Eval = " << dClass << endl;
  cout << "Weights:";
  for(int i = 0; i < NODES; i++){
    cout << " " << weights[i];
  }
  cout << endl;
}
cout << endl;
index = 0;
```

Now it works.

Comment: @jay, I think you were just looking at the wrong output field.

Comment: Ok so after getting the time to review this code, I noticed it is not printing out the right thing. The output array is the training set that the dClass variable tries to match. Look back to my edited question to see my output